# Route keeps getting redirected

Tags: angular

I am creating a simple photo gallery app. When the user selects an image, it should display the selected image. This is handled with a route to another component so when the user clicks on the image they want to view, the selected image is then displayed by itself through a different component. The issue I am having is that when I select an image on the UI, the url correctly changes to localhost:4200/gallery/1 (the 1 representing the id of the image) but only for a millisecond. It then redirects back to localhost:4200/gallery.

I have double checked my routes and from what I can tell they are setup correctly. I have nested the 'image-full-view' route as a child of the gallery route.

These are the relevant routes from my routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/gallery', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent, children: [
    { path: ':id', component: ImageFullViewComponent},
  ]},
```

This is the gallery html file where all the images are displayed (the router-outlet here should be the 'image-full-view' component below):

```
<ul class="container">
    <li class="item-list-container"><app-image-item
    class="image-item"
    *ngFor="let imageEl of images"
    [image]="imageEl"
    (click)="onImageSelect(imageEl.id)"
    ></app-image-item>
    </li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is the onImageSelect method from above which is stored in the gallery ts file:

```
onImageSelect(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/gallery', id])
    console.log(id);
  }
```

This is the 'image-full-view' html file where the selected Image should be displayed:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image-full-view" [src]="selectedImage.imagePath" alt="Man Praying">
    <p>{{ selectedImage.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Lastly, this is the 'image-full-view' ts file where the selectedImage is stored:

```
selectedImage: Image;

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap['id'];
    this.selectedImage = this.gallerService.getImage(id);
  }
```

Sorry, I know this is a lot of code but I have only included what I felt was relevant. Hoping someone can help!

Comment: As you mentioned you are navigating to `localhost:4200/gallery/1` with ID but in your routes you don't have any route check that once

Comment: can you please provide a working demo on stackblitz ?

Comment: I going to try and work out how to use stackblitz, I've never used it before! The route is there, it's a child of 'gallery' and it shows as: { path: ':id', component: ImageFullViewComponent}

Comment: Can't seem to get stackblitz to work :/ it keeps saying file not found for some of my components but It is the same format which is in VS code

Comment: I reproduced your code locally (as minimal working example) and it works fine. I guess the problem must be in another part of your app

Comment: Haven't been able to resolve this yet...does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but when I try and console.log the id variable from within the ngOnInit lifecycle hook in the 'image-full-width' component, NaN is logged to the console.